# Passing a list as an argument to a system of equations

Tags: python, list, function

I'm trying to pass a list as input to a system of functions. My function looks like this:

```
beta[i] - (1 - a[i]*beta[i])*(gamma + sum(other betas)

gamma = 0.49
a = [1.57, 2.731, 2.32, 4.681, 1.878]

def g(beta):
    return ((beta[0] - (1 - 1.57 * beta[0])*(gamma + np.sum([beta[1], beta[2], beta[3], beta[4]]))),
            (beta[1] - (1 - 2.731 * beta[1])*(gamma + np.sum([beta[0], beta[2], beta[3], beta[4]]))),
            (beta[2] - (1 - 2.32 * beta[2])*(gamma + np.sum([beta[0], beta[1], beta[3], beta[4]]))),
            (beta[3] - (1 - 4.681 * beta[3])*(gamma + np.sum([beta[0], beta[1], beta[2], beta[4]]))),
            (beta[4] - (1 - 1.878 * beta[4])*(gamma + np.sum([beta[0], beta[1], beta[2], beta[3]]))),
           )
```

which solves after calling:

```
optimize.fsolve(g, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

the answer is:

```
array([0.46713148, 0.30731229, 0.3502582 , 0.1932526 , 0.41133453]
```

Clearly, there must be more elegant way of doing this for arbitrary length of arguments. I'm trying the following:

```
def other_betas(lst, index):
    return sum(lst)-lst[index]

def temp(beta):
    for i in range(len(e)):
        beta[i] = (1 - e[i]*beta[i])*(gamma + np.sum(other_betas))
    return beta
```

which ends in:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'function'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it within one function as following:

```
def g(beta,a):
    n = len(a)
    summation = [beta[i] - (1 - a[i] * beta[i]) * (gamma + np.sum([beta[j] for j in range(n) if not j==i])) for i in range(n)]
    return tuple(summation)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to python - obviously and this comments are very helpful. Now, from the  answer by jeanggi90 I'm getting [-6.9, -18.9, -14.9, -33.0, -10.3]
 and with the answer by Vasilis G.: [7.049, 12.26,10.416,  21.017 ,8.43222] which is probably due to the function definition..

Comment: And I strongly believe that the true output must be: [0.46, 0.30, 0.35, 0.19, 0.41]

Comment: @QuantumJazz I think it was a misplaced bracket that changed the order of math operations. I edited my answer if you want to take a look.

Comment: Its great so far. Can it be made to work for arbitrary lists with just passing list a[...]?

Comment: It looks even leaner. Great!

Comment: @QuantumJazz that's good to know. Feel free to upvote or accept it as an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You did not call the function `other_betas()` the proper way since you forgot the brackets as well as passing the arguments to the function.

```
def other_betas(lst, index):
    return sum(lst)-lst[index]

def temp(beta):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        beta[i] = (1 - a[i]*beta[i])*(gamma + np.sum(other_betas(a, i)))
    return beta

print(temp(beta))
```

However, you could just sum up you list and subtract the corresponding element of `a` in the for loop. With list comprehension you do not even need the for loop.

```
def tempI(beta):
    mySum = gamma + np.sum(a)

    return [(1 - a[i]*beta[i])*(mySum - a[i]) for i,_ in enumerate(a)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, both codes work:

```
gamma = 0.49
a = [1.57, 2.731, 2.32, 4.681, 1.878]

def g(beta,n):
    lookup = {'0' : 1.57, '1' :  2.731, '2' : 2.32, '3' : 4.681, '4' : 1.878}
    summation = [( (1 - lookup[str(i)] * beta[i])) * (gamma + np.sum([beta[j] for j in range(n) if not j==i])) for i in range(n)]
    return tuple(summation)
```

and

```
def tempI(beta):
    mySum = gamma + np.sum(beta)

    return [(1 - a[i]*beta[i])*(gamma + np.sum(other_betas(beta, i))) for i,_ in enumerate(a)]
```

after calling the function  with:

```
optimize.fsolve(lambda beta: beta - g(beta, 5), [1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

we have:

```
array([0.46713148, 0.30731229, 0.3502582 , 0.1932526 , 0.41133453])
```